# Issues with selecting distinct records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am facing a problem with writing a MySQL query to fetch distinct results. Here is the scenario: I have a table named city as shown below. I have around 131k records now. I have to select the distinct cities. I tried to do substring but I don't know the length for each. Help in this regard is appreciated.

```
City
33098 Paderborn
Paderborn
Berlin
02826 Görlitz
10829 Berlin
Görlitz
```

Comment: Show us the queries you've tried so far

Comment: Do you have a pattern to work with? You seem to always have a "number-space-city" in some while only city in the others... It's almost impossible to fix this because some cities will feature a space so you can't split on the space at that point...

Comment: You could strip any numbers and leading spaces from the city name

Comment: Rule #1: Bad data in = bad data out.

Comment: well i worte query to Select distinct substring(city, 1, 10) from table but it did not work because the lenght is not constant.

Comment: well is it possible to check for numerics in the query.. and only to get the aplhabets out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with string formats.  If you assume that the numbers are at the beginning or end, you can use something like:

```
select distinct trim(' 0123456789' from city) as city
from t
```

This assumes that the only issue is the sequence of numbers and spaces at the beginning (or end) of the city name.

Comment: yeah, but still the problems remains because of inconsistent data any more suggestions ?

Comment: You need to give examples of what the problems are.